# Finding points of intersection of two curves

Tags: calculus, curves, intersection-theory

I have a problem where I needed to find the intersection of two curves, with $r=3+\sin(\theta)$ and $r=7\sin(\theta)$ for $[0<\theta<2\pi]$

I have that it's supposed to be $(7/6,\pi/6)$ and $(7/6,5\pi/6)$. The way I tried to do the problem based on the few examples my book gave is:

$3+\sin(\theta)=7\sin(\theta)$

$3=6\sin(\theta)$

$1=3\sin(\theta)$

$\sin(\theta)=1/3$

But I can't see any way to get the right values from that. What am I missing here? Am I missing something simple, completely misunderstanding how the problem is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the inverse function $\arcsin$ to get a value of $\theta$ in $(0,\pi/2)$. Then have a closer look at the $\sin$ function to get the other solution in $(\pi/2,\pi)$.

Comment: By the way, your calculation is wrong. It should be $1/2$ instead of $1/3$.

Comment: Indeed: $3=6\sin\theta$ implies $\sin\theta = \tfrac 1 2, r=\tfrac 7 2$, then $\theta = \tfrac \pi 6+2n\pi$. $~$ So the answer is: $$(r,\theta)\in \{(\tfrac 7 2, \tfrac \pi 6), (\tfrac 72, \tfrac {5\pi}6)\}$$

Comment: Ohh ok, I see. I just did something idiotic with my division....... thanks.....

Answer (score 1):

I plotted your curves and your solutions and they seem to match:

[image: polar curves and intersections] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGadV.png))